# c++ - sf::Thread freezes main thread when run in the while(window.isOpen()) loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml, freeze

I'm trying to launch an sf::Thread (because default C++ threads are hideously bad, as they crash constantly when executing them in the `while(window.isOpen())` loop) in my project, which displays a text in a box (This is suposed to be the text modification thread).

The issue arises when executing the thread in the `while(window.isOpen())` loop, where it freezes the main thread until it has finished execution. However, executing it before won't freeze the program and will run independently.

The thread is `sf::Thread t(std::bind(Display, std::ref(*messageBoxText), "some random things", 2000));`, where messageBoxText is a `sf::Text`, "some random things" is a `std::string` and 2000 is a `int` which states the millisecond delay.

The Display function is:

```
static void Display(sf::Text &text, std::string textToPut, int msDelay = 10000){
            conts int TEXT_NEWLINE_CONSTANT = 52; 
            int size = textToPut.size();

            vector<string> strings;

            const int numberOfNewlines{(size / TEXT_NEWLINE_CONSTANT) + 1};


            for(int i{0}; i < numberOfNewlines; i++){
                string tmp {""};
                for(int j{TEXT_NEWLINE_CONSTANT * i}; j < TEXT_NEWLINE_CONSTANT * (i + 1) && j < size; j++){
                    tmp += textToPut[j];
                }
                strings.push_back(tmp);
            }
    
            for(int i{0}; i < numberOfNewlines; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    text.setString(strings[i]);
                } else if (i > 0){
                    string tmp = strings[i - 1] + "\n" + strings[i];
                    text.setString(tmp);
                }
                sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(msDelay));
            }

            sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(msDelay * 2)); 
        }
```

Comment: _"...where it freezes the main thread until it has finished execution..."_ - __This destructor [of `sf::Thread`] calls `sf::Thread::wait()`, so that the internal thread cannot survive after its `sf::Thread` instance is destroyed"_ - see - https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Thread.php#a724b1f94c2d54f84280f2f78bde95fa0  Suggest you use `std::thread` and detach the thread.

Comment: Also - _"...because default C++ threads are hideously bad..."_ - please explain `std::thread` is a very thin wrapper around native OS threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suggest you use std::thread and detach the thread

Thank you for your suggestion. Changing

```
sf::Thread t(std::bind(Display, std::ref(*messageBoxText), "some random things", 2000));
t.launch();
```

to

```
std::thread t(std::bind(Display, std::ref(*messageBoxText), "some random things", 2000));
t.detach();
```

makes it work. Thanks!